# How Java process Method Inference Lambda Expression as method parameter?

Tags: java, methods, lambda, inference

In code below, method inference `iF::apply` is put into a `Map` in class `Context`.

But when using `get` method on the `Map` with `iF::apply`, we get `null`. Why?

Here is the debug info with IDEA:

[image]

Below is the code:

```java
    public void test() {
        Context context = new Context();
        IF iF = new IF();
        context.put(iF::apply, 100);
        Integer v = context.get(iF::apply);
        System.out.println(v);
    }

class IF implements Function<String, Integer> {
    @Override
    public Integer apply(String s) {
        return 200;
    }
}

class Context {
    private Map<Function, Object> items = new HashMap<>();

    public <T, R> void put(Function<T, R> name, R value) {
        items.put(name, value);
    }

    public <T, R> R get(Function<T, R> name) {
        return (R)items.get(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: `context.put(iF::apply, 100);` → `context.put(iF, 100);` and `context.get(iF::apply)` →  `context.get(iF)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code contains two `iF::apply` [Method Reference Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13). Each time it creates a new `Function<String, Integer>` instance.

Since those instances don't override `equals()` and `hashCode()` they are not really usable as keys in a `HashMap`. If you want to retrieve the entry that is already in the map you **must** use the same instance.

That these are different instances can be seen from your screenshot:

- the key in the map is `{App$lambda@648}`
- the argument that is provided to retrieve the entry is `{App$lambda@644}`

These names in the debug view are built using the simple classname (`App$lambda`) followed by `@` followed by some unique identifier per object that the debugger encountered.